# Question regarding path connected

Tags: general-topology

Prove that an open connected set in $R^2$ is path connected. Well there are few proofs given any forum, but most of them involve idea of components. But is it possible to solve it for a person who has no idea of components. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: So I think the best way for you is learn component

Comment: Who needs components to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be your open connected set. If $A=\emptyset$, then there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, take $a\in A$. Let$$O=\left\{b\in A\,|\,\text{there is a path in $A$ conneting $a$ to }b\right\}\text.$$The set $O$ is not empty, since $a\in A$. It is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ because, if $p\in O$, you can take an open disc $D(p,r)\subset A$. Then, since there is a path in $A$ from $a$ to $p$ and since there is a path in $A$ from $p$ to any element of $D(p,r)$, $D(p,r)\subset O$ and therefore $O$ is a neighborhood of all its points and so it is an open set. Finally, $O$ is a closed subset of $A$, because if $p\in A\setminus O$, then there is an open disc $D(p,r)$ contained in $A$ and if there was a path in $A$ from $a$ to any point of that thisc, then there would be a path in $A$ from $a$ to $p$ itself, which is a contradiction. So, $D(p,r)\subset A\setminus O$.

Since $O\subset A$, $O\neq\emptyset$, $O$ is an open subset of $A$, $O$ is a closed subset of $A$ and $A$ is connected, $O=A$. In other words, $A$ is path cannected.